# JDatePicker Date difference in Java

Tags: java, date, datepicker, calendar, date-difference

I created a GUI with several JDatePicker objects. Now I’m trying to compute the difference between two JDatePicker dates. But I don’t have a clue how to start. Can anyone help me please?
The date in the JDatePicker is a String object. I guess I need to convert the String into a date object and then convert it to a long object. Am I on the right path?

Comment: Start by representing your dates as `LocalDate` objects and using your search engine to find out how to get the difference between a couple of those. It’s described in many places.

Comment: Related (not the same question, but probably inspirational): [How to calculate difference between two date from DatePicker widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17496056/how-to-calculate-difference-between-two-date-from-datepicker-widget).

Comment: From what I read about [the SourceForge `JDatePicker`](https://github.com/JDatePicker/JDatePicker) it seems to be a very old component. It’s not that it’s from 2004, it’s more that it is still lacking integration with [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). I wonder if you could get a more modern date picker instead? Failing that, how does the string that you get from the date picker look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    Locale.setDefault(Locale.UK); // So that other readers can run the example; don’t include in your production code

    DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.LONG);

    String dateString1FromJDatePicker = "24 November 2019";
    String dateString2FromJDatePicker = "29 February 2020";

    LocalDate from = LocalDate.parse(dateString1FromJDatePicker, dateFormatter);
    LocalDate to = LocalDate.parse(dateString2FromJDatePicker, dateFormatter);
    long difference = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(from, to);

    System.out.println(difference);
```

Output from this example piece of code is:

> 97

It takes two steps:

1. Parse each date string into a `LocalDate`.
2. Use `ChronoUnit.DAYS.between()` for obtaining the difference in days between the two dates.

As a possibly better alternative you may look for a date picker component that has integration with java.time, the modern Java date and time API, so that you don’t need to parse the string yourself.

### Links

- [SourceForge `JDatePicker`](https://github.com/JDatePicker/JDatePicker).
- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.